# Use Quarkus MongoDB client

Tags: mongodb, quarkus

I have started exploring Quarkus with MongoDB client. I came across a lot of boiler plate code in the documentation. (esp. BSON)

refer: https://quarkus.io/guides/mongo-guide

Can't we make use of the annotations to generate the code.
Is this intentional to avoid the Reflection overhead.

Answer (score 0):

We have a lot of good things coming up for the MongoDB support in our next release (0.24.0 planned for Wednesday): it's called MongoDB with Panache.

You can see what it does in the documentation of the master branch here: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/mongodb-panache-guide.adoc .

So I would say, wait for 0.24.0 and give a try to this new feature (or you can build master and give it a try already), feedback is very welcome.

Comment: Can we expect something similar for Elasticsearch client ?